# java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 45

Tags: java, stringindexoutofbounds

I'm trying to make a program that takes in a string like: `KKKKKKKKKKKKKBCCDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDKKKKKMNUUUGGGGG`

And returns something like this: `$K13BCC$D15$K5MNUUU$G5`

Another example is `XYZAAAAAAGGTCCCCCCTTTAAAAAAAAAAAAAAKK`

Returns: `XYZ*A6GGT*C6TTT*A14KK`

But i get this StringIndexOutOfBoundsException when i try the first input, can anyone tell me why? Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class RunLengthEncoding {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner h = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s;
        char g;
        System.out.print("Enter input string: ");
        s = h.next();

        for (int d = 0; d < s.length(); d++){
            if (!Character.isUpperCase(s.charAt(d))){
                System.out.print("Bad input.");
                return;
            }
        }

        System.out.print("Enter flag character: ");
        g = h.next().charAt(0);

        if (g != '#' && g != '$' && g != '&' && g != '*'){
            System.out.println("Bad input.");
            return;
        }

        char c = s.charAt(0);
        String encode = "";

        for (int n = 0; n < s.length() - 1; n++){
            int k = 0;
            int j = 0;

            while (k + n < s.length() && s.charAt(k + n) == c){
                j++;
                k++;
            }

            if (j > 3){
                encode += g;
                encode += c;
                encode += j;
                n += j - 1;
            }

            else {
                encode += c;
            }
            c = s.charAt(n + 1);
        }
        System.out.println("Encoded: " + encode);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should debug your program to find this. If you are using an IDE then run the program in debug mode else you can use System.out.println() to print the values.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you are getting an out of bounds exception is because you are incrementing `n` outside of the for loop statement. You do this when you are doing `n += j - 1;`. This gives you an out of bounds exception because when you do `c = s.charAt(n + 1);`, n could be greater than or equal to the length of the string. As a general rule, you should not alter the value of the iteration variable in the for loop anywhere outside of the for loop. It makes the code harder to debug.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested in the solution I made:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RunLengthEncoding {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner h = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s;
        char g;
        StringBuilder encode = new StringBuilder();

        System.out.print("Enter input string: ");
        s = h.next();

        for (int d = 0; d < s.length(); d++) {
            if (!Character.isUpperCase(s.charAt(d))) {
                System.out.print("Bad input.");
                return;
            }
        }

        System.out.print("Enter flag character: ");
        g = h.next().charAt(0);

        if (g != '#' && g != '$' && g != '&' && g != '*') {
            System.out.println("Bad input.");
            return;
        }

        for (int n = 0; n < s.length(); n++) {
            int k = 1;

            while (n < s.length() - 1 && s.charAt(n) == s.charAt(n + 1)) {
                k++;
                n++;
            }
            if (k > 3) {
                encode.append(g).append(s.charAt(n)).append(k);
            }

            else {
                for (int c = 0; c < k; c++) {
                    encode.append(s.charAt(n));
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.print("Encoded: " + encode);
    }
}
```